# What is wrong with ```mydata <-(function(x){if(x>=y&x<=z) return(x)}```

Tags: r

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

`mydata <-(function(x){if(x>=y&x<=z) return(x)}`

It seems to work nice, but when I am trying to add values to it, it doesen’t work.
For example:

`mydata(x = 2:11, y = 5, z = 2)`

Comment: Please explain what you tried so far to solve the problems and what error messages you get. I did run your code and the error message shoudl give you a hint already what's wrong with you function: `unused arguments (y = 5, z = 2)`

Comment: I miss spelled the values. It should be mydata(x = 2:11, y = 5, z = 2)== 0.4 And with that i get "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used "

Comment: I added y and z to the functionmydata <- function(x, y, z), and still there is something wrong. Function should return x if it's values are between y and z.

Comment: The solution of Ronak Shah is exactly giving you this result, i.e. the x values that are in teh range of y and z. Check your input and clearly define what you want to achieve if that's not the result you are looking for.

Comment: Can you add couple of example input for the function along with expected output that you want for it. Maybe it will help to clarify what you want. What should `mydata(x = 2:11, y = 5, z = 2)` return? Add some more similar examples.

Comment: I think I need to create subvector for x for the values in x, which are between y and z. I suppose that would solve my problem. But i havent succeed to create subvector for x in mydata <-(function(x){if(x>=y&x<=z) return(x)}

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not know what is `y` and `z`. Do you need this ?

```
mydata <- function(x, y, z) x[x >= y & x<= z]       

mydata(x = 2:11, y = 2, z = 5)
#[1] 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you. I miss spelled the values. It should be mydata(x = 2:11, y = 5, z = 2)== 0.4 And with that i get "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used "

Comment: Hi,

`if` is one of the only thing in R that is not meant to be used with vectors but single values. If you want a vectorial "if" you can either use boolean like Ronak has shown (to filter) or `ifelse` that will return something in a case and another thing in another. Then, I don't understand your expected result (maybe Ronak got it).

Comment: I think I need to create subvector for x for the values in x, which are between y and z. I suppose that would solve my problem. But i havent succeed to create subvector for x in mydata <-(function(x){if(x>=y&x<=z) return(x)}

Comment: @ToveS Do you atleast know what output you want for the example you have shared?

Comment: my_data(x = 1:10, y = 2, z = 5) == 0.4

Comment: @ToveS What is `my_data(x = 1:10, y = 2, z = 5) == 0.4` supposed to mean? Can you show the output that you want?

Comment: I have to create function mydata <-(function(x){if(x>=y&x<=z) return(x)} and after that i shoul be able to run this (x = 1:10, y = 2, z = 5) == 0.4 with it. But i think there needs to be subvector for x values between y and z for i could run those values with the function